# Spark NullPointerException

Tags: nullpointerexception, apache-spark

My Spark code reads like this:-

```
val logData = sc.textFile("hdfs://localhost:9000/home/akshat/recipes/recipes/simplyrecipes/*/*/*/*")


def doSomething(line: String): (Long,Long) = { 


 val numAs = logData.filter(line => line.contains("a")).count();


 val numBs = logData.filter(line => line.contains("b")).count();
 return (numAs,numBs)

}

 val mapper = logData.map(doSomething _)

 val save = mapper.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://localhost:9000/home/akshat/output3")
```

mapper is of type `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Long, Long)] = MappedRDD`
When I try to perform saveAsTextFile action, it gives an error 
**java.lang.NullPointerException**

What I am doing wrong and what changes should I do to rectify this exception?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please put the complete stack trace here?

Answer (score 5):

You should not reference `logData` from within `doSomething`. This is the issue. I can't tell exactly what you are trying to do, but if all you are trying to do is count the lines with "a" in them, you don't need to do the `def`, just do:

```
val numAs = logData.filter(line => line.contains("a")).count();
val numBs = logData.filter(line => line.contains("b")).count();
```

If on the other hand you are trying to count "a" and "b" in each line, and write out a line for every input, then try this:

```
def doSomething(line: String): (Int,Int) = {
  val numAs = line.count(ch => ch.equals("a"))
  val numBs = line.count(ch => ch.equals("b"))
  (numAs, numBs)
}
```